# How to retrieve core motion datas like accelerometer or gyroscope datas at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, watchkit, core-motion

I want to create some array of coremotion datas. I am trying this code but it is writing only accelerometer.

How can i call gyroscope at the same time?

```
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue()) { (acce, error) in
    guard let acce = acce else {
        print(error ?? "Error occured with acce")
        self.finishRecording(success: false)
        return
    }

    let sensorData = "ACCELX: \(acce.acceleration.x), ACCELY: \(acce.acceleration.y), ACCELZ: \(acce.acceleration.z), TIME: \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)"
    self.sensorDatas.append(sensorData)
}

motionManager.startGyroUpdates(to: OperationQueue()) { (gyro, error) in
    guard let gyro = gyro else {
        print(error ?? "Error occured with gyro")
        self.finishRecording(success: false)
        return
    }

    let sensorData = "GYROX: \(gyro.rotationRate.x), GYROY: \(gyro.rotationRate.y), GYROZ: \(gyro.rotationRate.z), TIME: \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)"
    self.sensorDatas.append(sensorData)
}
```

Thanks.